# Как сохранить список из памяти python в CSV

Tags: python, csv

В общем я чистил список и теперь он очищенный лежит у меня в памяти. Как его сохранить как CSV в новый файл?

```
import csv
    #1
    f = open('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/main.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    list_emails1 = []

    for row in csv_f:
      list_emails1.append(row[0])

    #2
    f = open('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/2.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    list_emails2 = []

    for row in csv_f:
      list_emails2.append(row[0])
    #3
    f = open('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/3.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    list_emails3 = []

    for row in csv_f:
      list_emails3.append(row[0])
    #4
    f = open('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/4.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    list_emails4 = []

    for row in csv_f:
      list_emails4.append(row[0])

    list_emails1 = set(list_emails1)
    list_emails2 = set(list_emails2)
    list_emails3 = set(list_emails3)
    list_emails4 = set(list_emails4)

    notclean_list1 = list_emails1.difference(list_emails2)
    notclean_list2 = notclean_list1.difference(list_emails3)
    clean_list = notclean_list2 .difference(list_emails4)
    clean_list = set(clean_list)

    #write(clean_list)."/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/clean_list.csv"
    #writer = csv.writer(clean_list)
    #writer.writerows(someiterable)

    #cw = csw.writer(open("/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/clean_list.csv",'w'))

    #from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
    #import datetime as dt
    #dreader.DataReader(clean_list).to_csv(clean_list+'.csv')
    #df = pd.Data.Frame(clean_list, columns=["column"])
    #df.to_csv('clean_list.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример CSV (3-5 строк) в оригинальном формате?

Comment: 'email1@host.ru;;;', 'email2@host.ru;;;', email3@host.ru;;;', 'email4@host.ru;;;'}

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/*.csv')], 
               ignore_index=True)
df.drop_duplicates().to_csv('/home/iurii/Desktop/CSV1/clean_list.csv', 
                            index=False, header=None)
```